# directories manipulation in C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile

Tags: c#, directory

I'm trying to create the folder **desktop** in

```
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile
```

but I'm getting strange results there is no desktop folder in systemprofile but if I call

```
System.IO.Directory.Exists(@"C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\desktop")
```

it returns the value true. However if I go to the folder either using command line or explorer there is no desktop folder, and if I manually create the folder in explorer it does not complain about the folder already existing. so My question why does it return true?

The reason I want to know is that when I call

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\desktop");
```

nothing happens and I'm guessing its because Exists returns true.

also when I do something similar in

```
"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile"
```

everything works as expected.

**Answer**

in my case it was not virtual directories as others assumed when they marked my as a duplicate the problem was being caused because I was working remotely on the machine, Once I came into the office and ran the same code it all worked as expected.

Comment: Virtualized directories - Vista and up virtualizes calls to support older applications that want to write in "protected" directories. Your call to create did work, but it didn't put it where you think it did. See 2nd link in accepted answer on question above.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".